# Compilation error when compiling kernel on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiler-errors, makefile, kernel

I got this error while compiling kernel
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /usr/src/linux-2.6.34.13/block/cmps/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/linux-2.6.34.13/block/cmps/Makefile'. Stop.
make: *** [block/cmps] Error 2

Though I didn't at any point create or try to create a folder called cmps in the folder block. I created the folder cmps in the following directory /usr/src/linux-2.6.34.13/cmps/.
So what's this error about?

Comment: any signifance of using comps looking to the following error it looks like it goes to look for cmps in block folder and might be trying to make

Comment: @linux_fanatic why does it go look there? can't I redirect it to go and find cmps in the right location?

Comment: Can you share your Makefile here?